# Opening user profile from responses-answer tab leads to momentary error message

Tags: bug, status-norepro, profile-page, tooltips

Opening user profile from [responses-answer tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=responses&sort=answers) leads to momentary error message with text:

> Error occured while opening post body

> [image: error]

Same for "revisions" tab and "all" tab if current item is revision or answer.

Happen in FF 53.0.3 32bit Win7 Pro. No extentions were enabled.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Comment: @AdamLear This really happens in Firefox.

Comment: No repro in Firefox either. Any errors in the dev console, by any chance? Does this happen on every profile and post or just specific ones? (cc @VadimOvchinnikov)

Comment: @AdamLear I am facing this issue on every StackExchange community in all profiles. No errors in console. By the way the red message is `Error occurred when loading post body`. (сс @alexolut)